# Filling a table with information from other table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fill a table with information from other tables. Something like this:

```
$item = new item();
$item->save();

//this works
$item_actions-> new item_actions();
$item_actions->item_id = $item->id;
$item_actions->save();

//this doesn't work

$default_items = default_items::all();

foreach($default_items as $default_item)
{
$item_list = new item_list();
$item_list->item_id = $item->id;
$item_list->name = $default_item->name;
$item_list->save()
}

return back();
```

I have used `dd($default_items)` and it contains every single item from the default_items table. There is no error, the table is simply not filled and the program continues. The $item_actions, however, works, so there must something going on on that foreach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just to "insert" data in the DB, if your table is called "item_lists" you can try like this:

```
$dataSet = [];
foreach ($default_items as $default_item) {
    $dataSet[] = [
        'item_id'  => $item->id,
        'name'    => $default_item->name,
    ];
}

DB::table('item_lists')->insert($dataSet);
```

Maybe laravel will require the class for DB, so just add:

```
use DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing semicolon after save method within your loop

> $item_list->save();